# Babel just handle .js file into dist folder

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am trying to migrate my project to make use of ES6 features (like annotations)

The project folder has the structure below:

```
config/
--AppConfig.json
src/
-controllers/
---controller.js
-commons/
---lib.js
-utils/
---descriptor.json
-app.js
```

with this configuration, the /dist folder will contains just ".js" files and dont handle json files

so the "dist" folde will not be able to works normally.

Comment: It is not clear to me what kind of issue you are experiencing, can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @SilvioBiasiol, The babel will transpile files in src folder and will add it in dist folder. So, the files other than .js in src wont get transpiled and hence it wont add into dist folder. That's what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can add json or other types of files outside **src** folder.

The babel will transpile files in **src** folder and will add it in **dist** folder. So, the files other than **.js** in **src** wont get transpiled and hence it wont add into **dist** folder. That's what the problem is.

***Let me know if it helps.***

**PS-** Refer your babelrc file.

Comment: the dist folder is created to be the "packaged project" it has to work standalone. and what you mean by "outside" ? how files in dist folder will recognize path ? can you give me an example?

Comment: keep your `descriptor.json` at root level.